Segmentation 3D architectures
I would like to ask you for advice on the best solution for my problem. I have a task to segment an object based on some of its signal. That is, I have input objects of size T x H x W, where T is time. And at the output I want to get a volumetric mask of size D x H x W. That is, roughly speaking, I have a set of images of the signal for T seconds.
I'm trying to solve this problem using 3D convolutions and the architectures associated with them. I have already tried Unet3D, AttentionUnet3D, UNETR, TransU
net. These are the most basic ones I've tried. So far, my main problem is that conventional networks for 2D segmentation outperform 3D ones in terms of training time, but I don’t get a significant increase in quality. Can you give me some tips on what I should try?
If my question seems a little vague, then here are two questions I'd like answers to.

What architectures do you recommend for different tensors at the beginning and at the end? (i.e. let the input be 150 x 100 x 100, and the output 30 x 100 x 100)
What would be the best loss in such situations?

